# How can I maximize my FOB's farmability?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

If someone invades my FOB, I stand to lose far less than they stand to gain. I can only lose easily-farmed resources, easily-replaced guards, and the staff who weren't worth putting on direct contract. The invader can receive S++ rank **volunteers**, a prize far more valuable than the cost to either of us.

To give more people more S++ rank troops, I would gladly set all my platforms to zero security, but it looks like a recent change has made it so only really-high-security bases can give S++ rank volunteers. Thus, I need to weaken myself in a more sophisticated way.

How can I maximize my chances of **losing** FOB invasions, without getting the reward soldiers for invading me capped at S-rank? Are non-lethal defenses easier to breach than lethal? What weapon range sucks hardest? And can I use Key Security Zones to cluster my troops out of an invader's way?

Comment: (There are also rewards for winning a defense. I don't know if those can include S++ rank soldiers, but even if they can, I can't really encourage people to throw themselves at highly-effective defenses as well as I can encourage them to throw themselves at easily-exploited defenses. Heck, this might increase the number of defenses I win simply due to more people targeting me.)

Comment: +1. That is awesome!  What a great way to think and help others.

Answer (score 3):

I am not too big on how the actual ranking of the soldiers they get and the points work, but I do know a couple of things about the guards and traps.

> Are non-lethal defenses easier to breach than lethal?

**NO.** Non-lethal is **more difficult** than lethal. From my experience, this is for two reasons:

- Guards get free gas masks when you set them to non-lethal
- Resisting nonlethal attacks is all around harder for the player -- lethal weapons typically don't impede your movement, and life regenerates faster than your stamina or psyche or whatever it is.

> What weapon range sucks hardest?

I would have to say middle range. Long range gives them sniper rifles, which are powerful. Short range gives them shotguns, which are also powerful. Assault rifles and machineguns are the least threatening of those options.

I don't know if setting more traps adds to the value of the soldiers players get for infiltrating your FOB, but the least threatening traps are the decoys, obviously. Claymores are also pretty easy to avoid -- for me, anyway, some people just have a tragic lack of observational skill.

Comment: So for those choices, I can't really do better than default settings? Bummer. I suppose you've found gas weapons pretty effective for FOBs? I've been failing a lot with a tranq-heavy style; it's just too hard to get a round past a guard's arm in the short FOB reflex mode time.

Comment: Whoops, that rations thing was a brainfart. I have been playing all the older games (namely PW which is similar but has rations) and MGSV is the only one with regenerating health. Corrected now for anyone that thought I was an idiot. @user2357112 Sleeping gas grenades are nice because you don't have to aim, as you observed. You can put multiple people to sleep if you're lucky, though that sort of situation is extremely rare on FOBs. Also the structure of FOBs is good for grenades -- lots of tight corners, being able to throw grenades up on to catwalks, etc